# How to create the sectiondata in the react native sectionlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want show the data from my API use `Sectionlist` in the react native 
but I have no idea how to generate the `sectionData`.
I think my data is too complex to understand and let me confuse.
The struct like below

```
"Info": [
        {
            "Name": "test1",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "sss": "1215",
                    "aaa": "1010133000001",

                },
                {
                    "sss": "1215",
                    "aaa": "1010133000001",

                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "test2",
            "Data": [
                {
                    "sss": "1215",
                    "aaa": "1010133000001",

                },
                {
                    "sss": "1215",
                    "aaa": "1010133000001",

                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want show the `SectionHeader` use `Name`and show the Contents use `Data`.
Now I can get data use potion of code like below. How can I go on? Thank you!

```
for (let idx in jsonData) {
        let Item = jsonData[idx];
        console.log(Item.Name)
        for (let index in Item.Data) {
           Item2 = Item.Data[index];
          console.log(Item2.sss)
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to update your data array,

```
let newArray = []
for (let item in jsonData) {
    let dict = {
      title: item.Name,
      data: item.Data
    }         
    newArray.push(dict)
 }
```

After the above code, you will get the array for section list.

Then use this like the following,

```
...
    <SectionList
      renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <Text key={index}>{item.sss}</Text>}
      renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{title}</Text>
      )}
      sections={this.state.data}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
    />
    ...
```

The 'this.state.data' is your new array.
And `renderItem` is used for rendering section data
And `renderSectionHeader` is used for rendering section header.

Answer (score 0):

provide an array of items, this will spit out the section data

```
// maps it's an array of objects
// groupBy to extract section headers
let dataSource = _.groupBy(maps, o => o.name);
// reduce to generate new array
dataSource = _.reduce(dataSource, (acc, next, index) => {
  acc.push({
    key: index,
    data: next
  });
  return acc;
}, []);

return dataSource;
```